# What does a dot before the variable name in struct mean?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

looking at the linux kernel source, I found this:

```
static struct tty_operations serial_ops = {
  .open = tiny_open,
  .close = tiny_close,
  .write = tiny_write,
  .write_room = tiny_write_room,
  .set_termios = tiny_set_termios,
};
```

I've never seen such a notation in C.
Why is there a dot before the variable name?

Comment: This is used for *initialization* of struct members (they are not variables) in the "new" C99 style (some compilers may have used the same format even before C99 was issued).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is a [Designated Initializer](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html), which is syntax added for C99.
Relevant excerpt:

> In a structure initializer, specify the name of a field to initialize
> with ‘.fieldname =’ before the element value. For example, given the
> following structure,

```
struct point { int x, y; };
```

> the following initialization

```
struct point p = { .y = yvalue, .x = xvalue };
```

> is equivalent to

```
struct point p = { xvalue, yvalue };
```

Answer (score 14):

It's sometimes called "designated initialization". This is a C99 addition, though it's been a GNU extension for a while.

In the list, each `.` names a member of the struct to initialize, the so called designator.