# struct is it declaration or defination or some type of Object Oriented behavior in kernel source

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

In r8169_main.c in linux kernel source there is a struct like this

```
#define KBUILD_MODNAME "foo"

static struct pci_driver rtl8169_pci_driver = {
    .name       = KBUILD_MODNAME,
    .id_table   = rtl8169_pci_tbl,
    .probe      = rtl_init_one,
    .remove     = rtl_remove_one,
    .shutdown   = rtl_shutdown,
    .driver.pm  = pm_ptr(&rtl8169_pm_ops),
};
```

I like to in first member .name but there is no data type specified and there is `.` before `name` like `.name    = KBUILD_MODNAME,` what is it called. is this name member defined somewhere else what this static struct means I did not seen this type of struct before. Can any one please tell what is this and its even assigned a value in struct declaration???

can I also create array of this type of struct?

Comment: This does not declare a struct, this creates the variable `rtl8169_pci_driver` with type `struct pci_driver` and initializes it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a dot before the variable name in struct mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487918/what-does-a-dot-before-the-variable-name-in-struct-mean)

Comment: Yes as @tkausl says. You'll need to look for the struct definition elsewhere. Looks like it must be in a header file. I'd start with `pci.h`.

Comment: See [`include/linux/pci.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/pci.h#L886)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is it called.

`name` is a *member* of structure `struct pci_driver`.

The initialization form is called *designated initialization*. The part `.name = something` is *designator*.

> is this name member defined somewhere else

Yes, in [include/linux/pci.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/pci.h#L886).

> what this static struct means I did not seen this type of struct before

The line *defines* a variable `rtl8169_pci_driver` of type `struct pci_driver`. The `static` keyword modifies *variable* lifetime - it means the variable is valid for the whole duration of the program.

```
static struct pci_driver rtl8169_pci_driver = {...}
                                            ^^^^^^^ - initialization
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          - variable name
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                             - variable type
^^^^^                                               - storage specifier
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          - variable declaration
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - variable definition
```

Research https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration

> can I also create array of this type of struct?

You can create arrays of `struct pci_driver`s.

```
static struct pci_driver example_array[20] = {
   { .name = initilization_for_first_element, ... },
   { .name = initilization_for_second_element, ... },
   ... etc.
};
```